# Jorte sync NationalHolidayCalendar with Google Calendar

Tags: jorte

Is there any way to sync the NationalHolidayCalendar which the Jorte has with Google Calendar?The NationalHolidayCalendar of Jorte has been set up to show Greek Holidays.The google calendar shows greek national holidays ,but it only shows a few of them,while jorte shows most of them.So,I was wondering if there is anyway to sync the Jorte's NationalHolidayCalendar with Google Calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Jorte help pages](http://www.jorte.net/english/synchro.html):

1. Select `menu → Settings → Data Syncronization`
   [image]
2. If "Select synsapplication" is not checked, tap on "Select synsapplication" and have it checked.  [image] [image]
3. When the "Calendar" item is checked,
   synchronizing will start immediately.  [image] [image]